# PayPal PHP Fatal error: Class 'Sample\CreateOrder' not found and how to properly configure the PayPal checkout sdk environment

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, http-headers

Okay, this is going to be a two part question because I dont know which part is causing the problem.

**Question 1.**
I think the problem that I have might stem from the way I setted up the paypal checkout sdk environment. Here is a link to the tutorial I'm following https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/setup-sdk/ I am not positive where to place the HTTP Request Headers either on another page or inside the environment configuration page or if I even need them at all? Or if I have to configure the headers at all or place them as is?

Here is my HTTP Request Headers

```
$request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
$request->headers["prefer"] = "return=representation";
```

Here is my environment configuration

```
namespace Sample;

use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment;

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // or error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');

class PayPalClient
{
    /**
     * Returns PayPal HTTP client instance with environment that has access
     * credentials context. Use this instance to invoke PayPal APIs, provided the
     * credentials have access.
     */
    public static function client()
    {
        return new PayPalHttpClient(self::environment());
    }

    /**
     * Set up and return PayPal PHP SDK environment with PayPal access credentials.
     * This sample uses SandboxEnvironment. In production, use ProductionEnvironment.
     */
    public static function environment()
    {
        $clientId = getenv("CLIENT_ID") ?: "Aa2IfcoEvHnfJRnVQLSFrSs3SmTTkv5N1weMEL66ysqYIeHfAqXpDVkjOv3vLhkhbP4eKB6MpRlQIcJw";
        $clientSecret = getenv("CLIENT_SECRET") ?: "EF6l6PDQJEZbdKTeg35pbBSft6WRdALQC3Xrl5vvG0VNgBUehQyTCQ09QdIauxoccvJOf5Aoy-OGsH5G";
        return new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
    }
}
```

**Question 2.**
I have been trying to update a transaction that a user will place using the PayPal Checkout. Here is a link to the tutorial I'm following https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/update-order-details/

I get the following error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Sample\CreateOrder' not found on line 78
```

The error is found on line 78 which is the piece of code found below.

```
$createdOrder = CreateOrder::createOrder(true)->result;
```

Here is the full code.

```
namespace Sample;
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

//1. Import the PayPal SDK client that was created in `Set up the Server SDK`.
use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersPatchRequest;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersGetRequest;
class PatchOrder
{

    // 2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
    public static function patchOrder($orderId)
    {
        // 3. Call PayPal to patch the transaction details
        $client = PayPalClient::client();
        $request = new OrdersPatchRequest($orderId);
        $request->body = PatchOrder::buildRequestBody();
        $client->execute($request);
        $response = $client->execute(new OrdersGetRequest($orderId));
        print "Status Code: {$response->statusCode}\n";
        print "Status: {$response->result->status}\n";
        print "Order ID: {$response->result->id}\n";
        print "Intent: {$response->result->intent}\n";
        print "Links:\n";
        foreach($response->result->links as $link)
        {
            print "\t{$link->rel}: {$link->href}\tCall Type: {$link->method}\n";
        }
        print "Gross Amount: {$response->result->purchase_units[0]->amount->currency_code} {$response->result->purchase_units[0]->amount->value}\n";
        // To toggle printing the whole response body comment/uncomment below line
        echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), "\n";
    }

    /*
    *
    * Build sample PATCH request
    */
    private static function buildRequestBody()
    {
        return array (
            0 =>
                array (
                    'op' => 'replace',
                    'path' => '/intent',
                    'value' => 'CAPTURE',
                ),
            1 =>
                array (
                    'op' => 'replace',
                    'path' => '/purchase_units/@reference_id==\'PUHF\'/amount',
                    'value' =>
                        array (
                            'currency_code' => 'USD',
                            'value' => '200.00',
                            'breakdown' =>
                                array (
                                    'item_total' =>
                                        array (
                                            'currency_code' => 'USD',
                                            'value' => '180.00',
                                        ),
                                    'tax_total' =>
                                        array (
                                            'currency_code' => 'USD',
                                            'value' => '20.00',
                                        ),
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
        );
    }
}

if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
{
    print "Before PATCH:\n";
    $createdOrder = CreateOrder::createOrder(true)->result;
    print "\nAfter PATCH (Changed Intent and Amount):\n";
    PatchOrder::patchOrder($createdOrder->id);
}
```

Comment: Please stick to one question per post.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, I think each question is related to the problem.

Comment: First off, the first question doesn't actually contain any explanation about any specific issue but rather "How do I...". The second question does include an error message. Stick to that one. If you get an answer and it answers your first question, great. If it doesn't, then ask a new question. Currently, this is too broad.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, point taken but I have been trying to figure out the problem and I feel each is related to the problem.